# Excel #VALUE! error when using GetValue

Tags: excel, vba, getvalue

I am attempting to use the code

```
Private Function GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref)
'   Retrieves a value from a closed workbook
    Dim arg As String
'   Make sure the file exists
    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
    If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
        GetValue = "File Not Found"
        Exit Function
    End If
'   Create the argument
    arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & _
      Range(ref).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)
'   Execute an XLM macro
    GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
End Function
```

But receive #VALUE! when used as shown below:

Target  ='C:\Temp[pulltest.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1

Parameters  C:\Temp\
            pulltest.xlsx
            Sheet1
            A1

Function    =getvalue(B3,B4,B5,B6)

I'm using Excel2010 in Windows 7.

Grateful for any help

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the `GetValue` function cannot be called from a worksheet cell.

So the following works:

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetVal()
    Dim path As String, file As String, sheet As String, ref As String

path = [a7]
file = [a8]
sheet = [a9]
ref = [a10]

[a11] = GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref)

End Sub

Private Function GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref)

     'Retrieves a value from a closed workbook
    Dim Arg
     'Make sure the file exists
   If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
   If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
       GetValue = "File not  Found"
       Exit Function
    End If
     'Create the argument
    Arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & CStr(sheet) & "'!" & Range(ref).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)

    GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Arg)
End Function
```

If the link is still active, you may refer to 
[Excel Tips from John Walkenbach: A VBA Function To Get A Value From A Closed File](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/a_vba_function_to_get_a_value_from_a_closed_file/)  which includes the caveat "**Note: You cannot use this function in a worksheet formula.**"

Comment: I had intended to use this function to import 14 data items from around 35 workbooks each month. I guess it's of not much use in that situation?

Comment: Why not?  Just run the macro instead of the function.  You could just store the argument values in worksheet cells, and iterate through them; or use it in any number of ways.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, but thanks again for your contributions.

Comment: As you learn more about using VBA, what I wrote will become more clear.

Comment: As you can tell, I'm not that familiar with VBA and  moreover it's unlikely  I'll ever use it again. I'd hoped to use it in this unusual (for me) situation. But as I can't invest the time in building on the code you have supplied, I will have to change the approach I was hoping to use. Regards.